# How can I draw a plot by using cut function in R?

Tags: r, plot, cut

This is the question that I need to solve for R. What I have worked is down below, but I currently can't find what's wrong with my code. Could you please help me?

When x, y objects are given, according to the x interval value changed to interval data
Create a function plot_user1 that plots the different y values.

(1) Both x and y are given as numeric vectors of the same length, and both vectors are paired data. (2) cut_breaks is the number of sections designated by the user when dividing the numeric vector x into section data. Through this, a graph is drawn with y at the index position corresponding to x having the same interval value.
Therefore, the number of graphs is drawn as much as the number of sections of x. (hint: use cut function)
(3) plot_name indicates the shape of the graph to be drawn with the corresponding y values.
It has one of three values: “boxplot”, “histogram”, and “scatter plot”.
(4) color indicates the color of the graph

(1) All conditional graphs of y according to the x section value are drawn on one page.
(2) The name of the x-axis of each graph is the level of the section, and the name of the y-axis is “y”.
(3) In relation to the graph layout, the inner margin is c(4,4,2,2) and the outer margin is c(2,2,5,2). (4) If plot_name has a value other than the three values ​​mentioned above,
"Errors: The plot_name is incorrect." string is output.
(5) The title of the graph collection is “The conditional boxplot (or scatter plot or
histogram) of y|x” and depends on the input plot_name value.
(hint: use outer =TRUE argument to title function)

```
plot_user1<-function(x,y,cut_breaks,plot_name,color) {
if(plot_name=="boxplot") {
    plot_name <- boxplot
    txt <- "The conditional boxplot of y|x"
    }
else if (plot_name == "histogram") {plot_name <- hist
    txt <- "The conditional histogram of y|x"
    }
else if (plot_name == "scatter plot") {plot_name <- plot
    txt <- "The conditional scatter plot of y|x"
    }
else {print("Errors: The plot_name is incorrect.")}
a<-cut(x,cut_breaks)
for (i in 1: cut_breaks) {
    plot_name(a,y,col=color,xlab=levels(a),ylab="y")
    title(main=txt, outer=TRUE)
    par(mar=c(4,4,2,2))
    par(oma=c(2,2,5,2))
}
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkkCq.png)
[image]

The plot that I have to draw needs to look like this.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are you trying to get a scatter plot after you've cut the x axis into an array containing factors?

Comment: The plot can either be a boxplot, histogram, or scatter plot according to what we type into the plot_name

Comment: Once the `x` variable is `cut`, the result will produce a box plot when calling the `plot` function and will error if the `hist` function is called. The only option that will work is `boxplot`. The for loop in the code plots the same thing 3 times.

Comment: Then how can I make several plots?

Comment: You would have to iterate over all possible levels of the `a` variable and you would need to filter the data so that only the x and y values for the current `a` level are included for each plot. You would also need to work out how to plot multiple graphs so they don't overwrite each other.  More fundamentally, you should post examples of your `x` and `y` data (use `dput(x)` and include the result in the original question). It would be worth doing `plot(x,y)` then `hist(x,y)` and finally `boxplot(x,y)` because this might reveal some errors.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But I still don't get this part "You would have to iterate over all possible levels of the a variable and you would need to filter the data so that only the x and y values for the current a level are included for each plot." I'm not sure how to code this part:(

Comment: Post some sample data as suggested. There's a possibility that what you want to achieve cannot be done with your data.

Comment: Oh I thought I posted the sample data! It is x=rnorm(200,0,1), y=rnorm(200,1,5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure if I understand you correctly but this gives the expected plots,

```
plot_user1<-function(x,y,cut_breaks,plot_name,color) {
    if(plot_name=="boxplot") {
        plot_name <- boxplot
        txt <- "The conditional boxplot of y|x"
        }
    else if (plot_name == "histogram") {plot_name <- hist
        txt <- "The conditional histogram of y|x"
        }
    else if (plot_name == "scatter plot") {plot_name <- plot
        txt <- "The conditional scatter plot of y|x"
        }
    else {print("Errors: The plot_name is incorrect.")}

    a<-cut(x,cut_breaks)
    par(mfrow=c(1,cut_breaks))


    for (i in levels(a)) {

        plot_name(y[levels(a)==i],col=color,xlab=i,ylab="y")
        title(main=txt, outer=TRUE)
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think it gives the expected plots as well! But the levels are slightly different from what I posted. Why is this a bit different?

Comment: It stems from the randomly selected data set. The `x` and `y` have been created randomly which makes them different from computer to computer unless you don't define `set.seed()`.

Comment: Thank you soso very much for your help!! It really helped a lot!! Oh and for the inner margin and outer margin, can I just add them like par(mfrow=c(1,cut_breaks),mar=c(4,4,2,2),oma=c(2,2,5,2))?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used them before. So I am not sure.  By the way, if this post answers your question,  you can accept it to close it. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to see how you can handle.